# Quantum channel that changes the temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-information

Are there known examples of quantum channels that describe heating up or cooling down a system? That is to say, for any Gibbs/thermal state at some temperature $T$ as input, the channel output is also a Gibbs/thermal state of a higher or lower temperature.

Comment: You would have to encode the underlying Hamiltonian in the channel.

Comment: I see. So there isn't a universal channel that does it.